# How do I add space between List items in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to add space between each list item and separate them out (see images for further explanation).

I have tried adding padding, but it only adds to the text, not the items themselves.

What I Have:
[image: Before]

What I Want:
[image: Goal]

Comment: Share some code of list

Comment: What you want looks like 3 different `Section`s each with a single row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Sweeper is correct. You want to place each view from the `List` in a `Section`. That will separate each concert artist and date from each other. Adjust spacing according to however you want it.

```
List {
   Section {}
   Section {}
   Section {}
}
```